# How to change end session message "I'm having trouble connecting to the server, please refresh the page"-Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant

I am doing the chatbot for another language and I would like to change the message after en session: **"I'm having trouble connecting to the server, please refresh the page"**.

I don't find where it is define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [Node.js implementation provided by IBM](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple), you can customize the message by editing line 76 of api.js ([located here for reference](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple/blob/c9278bb4f209fbb81fd799c6636c4bf2bad29b6a/public/js/api.js#L76)).